# Escaping dash in `dch` call

Tags: debian, command, arguments

I'm using `dch` to modify the changelog for a debian package that is being built using some bash script. The messages for changelog are taken from some data source and are just passed to `dch --append`.

And today I noticed that it fails to do its job if starts with dash (`-`) character:

```
$ dch --append "- when"
Unknown option:
Unknown option: w
Usage: dch [options] [changelog entry]
Run dch --help for more details
```

How would one properly escape such a string?

Comment: `dch --append -- "- when"` like for every command using getopt(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double dash to force the next not to be interpreted as command:

```
$ dch --append -- "- when"
$ head debian/changelog 
canto (0.7.10-4.1) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium

  * Non-maintainer upload.
  * Standards Version 3.9.5
  * - when



canto (0.7.10-4) unstable; urgency=low
```